# How to change hidden node so its transparent instead of completely disappearing?

Tags: sigma.js, linkurious

I was looking at this example of setting the filters for min degrees. When nodes are filtered, the node becomes transparent rather than disappearing completely in my code. Is there another setting I need to set for this?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Linkurious/linkurious.js/media/filters.gif

Answer (score 1):

you can make it the same color as the background

Comment: How do I change the color for hidden nodes? Its currently disappearing and I want it to be some what faded.